# How to literally translate this: 在赶路时，用尽全力地向前冲?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

经过沟通，大导演总算搞明白了，当地人自古就有一种习俗：在赶路时，用尽全力地向前冲，但每走上三天，便要休息一天。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 26. I need your help in the literal translation of this part: 在赶路时，用尽全力地向前冲。

So far, I have reached here:

在(in)赶路(hurrying)时(time)，用尽(to use up or to deplete)全力地(fully)向前(forward or ahead)冲(沖 to pour water on or 衝 to go straight ahead)

As you can see, the last part doesn't make much sense. Any help?

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense? 向前衝 means "dash forward"

Comment: I perplexed the 沖 with the 衝, but I think that I still miss something. 用尽 is the verb and 向前冲 is the noun? Something like: 用尽全力地向前冲 = They depleted with all their power the "dashing forward"? Something like that?

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see, the last part doesn't make much sense.

I don't see that.

经过沟通，
By connecting the dots,
大导演总算搞明白了，
it finally dawned on the great director,
当地人自古就有一种习俗：
since ancient times the local people have a custom:
在赶路时，
en route to somewhere,
用尽全力地向前冲，
(they) use up all their strength to dash forward,
但每走上三天，
but, after three days of walking (like that),
便要休息一天。
(they) take a rest for one day.

Answer (score 1):

"衝" means "charge".

- 用尽全力地向前冲 - charges forward/ahead with full/all strength.

Comment: In that case, what is the meaning and the function of 用尽?

Comment: 用尽全力 -- use up all your strength

Comment: 用尽, as indicated by @user2249675, is "used up" or "exhausted". I think you can add it to the end of the sentence - "...with full/all strength has been used up/exhausted."

Answer (score 1):

Having 地 in 用尽全力地 makes it  an adverb phrase, and that modifies the verb 向前衝 (dash forward)

用尽全力 = exhaust all power

用尽全力地 = in a manner of exhausting all power

用尽全力地向前衝 = dash forward in a manner of exhausting all power = madly dash forward